# How to evaluate this integral using Cauchy's residue theorem?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d\epsilon}{2\pi} f(\epsilon) 
\left[
\frac{1}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_n +i0^+)^2(\epsilon-\epsilon_m +i0^+)} - \frac{1}{(\epsilon-\epsilon_n -i0^+)^2(\epsilon-\epsilon_m -i0^+)}
\right]
$$
According to [the research article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.3446) (Appendix D), if we use Cauchy's residue theorem, the integral becomes
$$
I=- 
\left[
\frac{f(\epsilon_m)-f(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n)^2} + \frac{f'(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m)}
\right]
$$

here $f(\epsilon)=(e^{\beta\epsilon}+1)^{-1}$ and $0^+$ shows a infinitisimal small positive number. And $f'(\epsilon_n)=\frac{\partial f(\epsilon_n)}{\partial \epsilon_n} $.

**My attempt:**

Call the first term of $I$, $I_1$, and second term $I_2$. We have
$$
I=I_1+I_2
$$
*Calculating $I_1$:*

To evaluate $I_1$ I look at the following contour integral:
$$
I_u=\int_{C_u} \frac{dz}{2\pi} 
\left[
\frac{1}{(e^{\beta z}+1)(z-z_n )^2(z-z_m)}
\right]
$$
here $C_u=C_R+C$ is a semi-circle contour of radius $R$ in the upper plane of complex space, shown below

[image]

the two black dots are $z_{m(n)}=\epsilon_{m(n)}+i0^+$. In my understanding, this contour integral is equal to $I_1$ because the contribution of $C_R$ part of the contour $C_u$ goes to zero in the limit $R\to \infty $ (am I right?). And the remaining part contour $C$ becomes equal to $I_1$ in the limit $R\to \infty $. Next, I can use the residue theorem
$$
\int_{C_u} g(z)dz=2\pi i \times \sum_k \text{Res}(g(z),z_k)
$$
In our integral, we have three $z_k$ points,

1. $ z_1 = z_m $ is simple pole
2. $ z_2 = z_n $ is second order pole
3. $ z_3 = i\pi(2n+1)/\beta $ is a set of pole with $n \in \mathbb{Z} $

The residues at each $z_k$ are

1. $\text{Res}(g(z),z_1) = f(z_m)\frac{1}{(z_m-z_n )^2}= f(\epsilon_m)\frac{1}{(\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n )^2}$
2. $\text{Res}(g(z),z_2) = \lim_{z\to z_2} \frac{d}{dz}\left[f(z)\frac{1}{(z-z_m)}\right]= -f(\epsilon_n)\frac{1}{(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m )^2} + f'(\epsilon_n)\frac{1}{(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m )} $
3. $\text{Res}(g(z),z_3)$. I don't know how to calculate this residue. Any help?

All in all, we have
$$
I_1 = I_u =  i\left(
\frac{f(\epsilon_m)-f(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n )^2}
+ \frac{f'(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m )} +\text{Res}\left(g(z),z_3\right)\right)
$$

*Calculating $I_2$:*

Next, I do the same procedure for $I_2$ but with $z_{m(n)}=\epsilon_{m(n)}-i0^+$. The contour integral that is related to $I_2$ is
$$
I_d=-\int_{C_d} \frac{dz}{2\pi} 
\left[
\frac{1}{(e^{\beta z}+1)(z-z_n )^2(z-z_m)}
\right]
$$
here $C_d$ is a semi-circle in the down plane of complex space. Now the poles are again at $z_m, z_n$, and $i\pi(2n+1)/\beta$. By residue theorem, I will get
$$
I_2 = I_d = - i\left(
\frac{f(\epsilon_m)-f(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_m-\epsilon_n )^2}
+ \frac{f'(\epsilon_n)}{(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_m )} +\text{Res}\left(g(z),z_3\right)\right)=-I_1
$$

Hence, $I=0$

Can anyone please help me, why is my answer zero? It seems like I am double counting the poles.

Comment: Just close the contour in the upper-half of complex plane. The integrand declines rapidly enough, so the integral along this half-circle with the radius $R\to\infty$ does not contribute. Only the second term of the integrand is in play: it contains the poles inside the contour (the double-pole at $\epsilon=\epsilon_n+i0^+$ and the single pole at $\epsilon=\epsilon_m+i0^+$). The residues evaluation is straightforward.

Comment: @Svyatoslav thank you so much for the reply. Can you please explain it more? I am confused about how we get derivative $f'(\epsilon_n)$. If you could write an answer, it would be great, I would be able to tick it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Hello my friend.  There are poles at $z=-i(2k+1)\pi/\beta$, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.  So, there should be a series involved.  Yet, it is absent from the stated solution.  Then again, the other part of the integrand vanishes provided neither $\varepsilon_n$ not $\varepsilon_m$ is equal to a pole of $f$.

Comment: @Mark Viola, yes, you are right. For this function the first term also plays, cancelling these poles.

Comment: The derivative appears when you evaluate the residues at the double pole: $Res_{\epsilon =\epsilon_n+i0^+}=-\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon-\epsilon_m-i0^+}\Big|_{\epsilon=\epsilon_n}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I have edited the question. I have written my progress so far. I think I am getting closer to the answer. Can you please have a look at it and tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: For you first integral ($I_1$) the poles are $\epsilon=\epsilon_n-i0; \epsilon_m-i0; \, \frac{2k+1}{\beta}\pi i, k=0,1,2...$, and $\epsilon=\epsilon_n-i0; \epsilon_m-i0$ are outside your contour - they do not contribute. So, for $I_1$ you have only poles at $\epsilon=\frac{2k+1}{\beta}\pi i, k=0,1,2...$. For your second integral I would suggest closing the contour also in the upper half-plane, and for $I_2$ you will have inside the contour the poles at $\epsilon=\epsilon_n+i0; \epsilon_m+i0; \, \frac{2k+1}{\beta}\pi i, k=0,1,2...$

Comment: Oh yes yes, I took the wrong poles. Thank you very much for the answer.